# Поменять блоки местами на маленьком экране

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

```
function windowSize(){
    if (jQuery(window).width() <= '995'){
        var pdiv = jQuery('#fw_c > div:nth-child(5) > div > div > div.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_inner.vc_row-fluid > div:nth-child(2)').parent('#fw_c > div:nth-child(5) > div > div > div.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_inner.vc_row-fluid > div:nth-child(2)');
        pdiv.insertAfter(pdiv.next());
    } 
}

jQuery(window).load(windowSize); // при загрузке
jQuery(window).resize(windowSize); // при изменении размеров
```

Нужна правка, есть `#fw_c > div:nth-child(5) > div > div > div.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_inner.vc_row-fluid > div:nth-child(2)` нужно поставить его после `#fw_c > div:nth-child(5) > div > div > div.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_inner.vc_row-fluid > div:nth-child(3)`

Comment: Теперь я видел все

Comment: видел он помог бы =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так, повторил Вашу html структуру: http://jsfiddle.net/9kvqa4rx/1/.
Увеличивайте/уменьшайте окно с выводом, и квадраты Two и Three будут меняться местами.

```
var two = $('#fw_c > div:nth-child(5) > div > div > div.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_inner.vc_row-fluid > div:nth-child(2)');

var three = $('#fw_c > div:nth-child(5) > div > div > div.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_inner.vc_row-fluid > div:nth-child(3)');

window.onresize = function(){
    if(window.innerWidth <= 550){
        two.insertAfter(three);
    } else {
        three.insertAfter(two);
    }
}
```

Но необходимо также учитывать Ваши css свойства, т.к они могут изменить поведение.